# Do singletons use encapsulation?

Tags: design-patterns, encapsulation, singleton

I'm reading the Design patterns book by the Gang of 4. Does a singleton use encapsulation? To me it would seem like yes, but i'm not 100% sure.  Maybe I don't have a good understanding of encapsulation.

Comment: The class that the singleton makes into a single instance (if it is properly designed) uses encapsulation.

Comment: can you elaborate? How would I know if I violated encapsulation?

Comment: In other words, the Singleton doesn't affect how well (or how poorly) your class being singleton'd observes encapsulation.  The only thing a Singleton class (or the Singleton code placed into a class) sdoes is limit you to a single class instance.  It doesn't affect your overall encapsulation, except that you won't have to worry about multiple instances encapsulating separate state sets, but only one instance.

Comment: To put it another way, if your class has crappy encapsulation, it will still have crappy encapsulation after you turn it into a Singleton.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of a commonly agreed upon canonical definition of “encapsulation” but I believe that we can require at least the following.

> An object's internals are encapsulated if it is not possible to transform the object into an invalid state (where its invariants are broken) via its public interface.

The public interface of the singleton class consists of a single static function `getInstance` plus whatever interface the singleton object actually provides (this is not part of the pattern). The `getInstance` function clearly cannot be used to bring anything in an invalid state because all it does is creating an instance via the default constructor and caching it in a global variable. Whether the actual (useful) interface of the class obeys encapsulation is up to its implementer. (Because the default constructor is private, it would in principle be allowed to construct an object in an invalid state but let's assume it doesn't.)

Considering the encapsulation of the rest of the class, the singleton pattern doesn't change anything about it. Or, as [Robert Harvey](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1204/robert-harvey) has put it in the comments:

> A Singleton doesn't bring any encapsulation to the table that a class doesn't already have. If a class has poor encapsulation, it will still have poor encapsulation after it is turned into a Singleton. A Singleton restricts a class to a single instance, and that's all that it does.

On the other hand, if your class was properly encapsulated in the first place, making it a singleton will not destroy that property. The singleton pattern violates another important principle, though. The *single responsibility principle*. It basically says that each component should do one job and do it well. (See the comments below for a somewhat different opinion.) The singleton pattern couples the business logic the class performs together with the rules who may create an instance of it and how many. This leads to tighter coupling between it and its consumers than desirable and makes especially testing needlessly hard. Nowadays the singleton is considered an antipattern by many. Much has been said about it so here is only one video from Google's *Clean Code Talks* on the topic: [“Global State and Singletons” by Miško Hevery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI).

Comment: Per your last point: I am not convinced that singletons violate SRP. Most importantly, they are thinly-veiled global variables.

Comment: 2 things - 1 - if the constructor made the object in a valid state, would it utilize encapsulation?  2 - the clean code talks series is great! I wasn't aware of that until now. are there similar resources i should be aware of?

Comment: @user11235813: I'm afraid you're missing the point.  A Singleton doesn't bring any encapsulation to the table that a class doesn't already have.  If a class has poor encapsulation, it will still have poor encapsulation after it is turned into a Singleton.  A Singleton restricts a class to a single instance, and that's all that it does.

Comment: @Snowman Yes, it's basically a global variable except you only have mediated access to it. I've re-worded the sentence about the “primary reason” if that is less evident than I thought. How (if not as an SRP issue) would you characterize the problem that the class itself manages its instantiation and life-time? Or do you think that that's not an issue actually?

Comment: @5gon12eder Classes have constructors which manage instantiation, so I have always found a class that is its own factory to be a weak argument that it violates SRP. Which, by the way, is about _change_ and not _what an object does_, and is aimed at the method level, not the object/class level. In most languages, "singleton" is not about lifecycle management anyway, because modern languages do not have explicit memory management and the class that creates the one instance does not destroy it.

Comment: Anyway, you make some good points, I just think the part about "singletons violate software engineering principles" is not as precise as it could be.